# Node js return any of req.params.id XML element app.get

Tags: xml, node.js

this code returns content only if I type last xml's element's ID.
I want to content and page be loaded when I type any of element's ID.
How to do that?

```
 var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
 var xml = ('/Path/Apples.xml');
 fs.readFile(__dirname + '/Apples.xml', function (err, data) {


     var xmlStr = data.toString();
     var xmlDoc2 = libxmljs.parseXmlString(xmlStr);
 var Apple = xmlDoc2.get('Apples').childNodes();

    for (var i = 0; i < Apple.length; i++) {
     var nameattr = xmlDoc2.get('Apples').get('Apple').attr('id').value();
     var AppleId = Apple[i].attr('id');

     if (AppleId !== null) {
         var AppleIdVal = AppleId.value();
         console.log('somename ' + AppleIdVal);

         app.get('/obj/:id', function (req, res) {
             if (req.params.id == AppleIdVal) {


                 console.log('nameAttr: ' + AppleIdVal);
                 res.json('This is id: ' + AppleIdVal);

             }


         });
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only function closures can capture current variable values like that, not `if () {}` blocks. Also, you're currently adding a bunch of duplicate routes every time `AppleId` is not `null`. Consider rewriting your logic, for example:

```
var libxmljs = require('libxmljs');

var xmlDoc2, Apple;

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/Apples.xml', function(err, data) {
  xmlDoc2 = libxmljs.parseXmlString(data.toString());
  Apple = xmlDoc2.get('Apples').childNodes();

  // move your `app.listen()` here instead so that the file will have been read
  // before processing any requests
});

app.get('/obj/:id', function (req, res) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Apple.length; i++) {
    var nameattr = xmlDoc2.get('Apples').get('Apple').attr('id').value(),
        AppleId = Apple[i].attr('id');

    if (AppleId !== null) {
      var AppleIdVal = AppleId.value();
      if (req.params.id == AppleIdVal)
        return res.json('This is id: ' + AppleIdVal);
    }
  }
  res.json('id not found');
});
```

Additionally, you may consider swapping out the for-loop for code that does a single xpath lookup to find the `id`.